# Objective-C runtime switch class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, runtime

I define class MyClass as subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. 
In iOS 6 class UITableViewHeaderFooterView exist, and all works normally.
In iOS 5 class UITableViewHeaderFooterView do not exist, and MyClass do not registered in runtime.

In comments of file 'objc-runtime.m' says:
 * A class when first seen in an image is considered "unconnected". 
 * It is stored in `unconnected_class_hash`. If all of the class's 
 * superclasses exist and are already "connected", then the new class 
 * can be connected to its superclasses and moved to `class_hash` for 
 * normal use. Otherwise, the class waits in `unconnected_class_hash` 
 * until the superclasses finish connecting.

But when I dynamically create UITableViewHeaderFooterView class as subclass UITableHeaderFooterView, MyClass do not connected (+load not invoked), and I get error:
Unknown class MyClass in Interface Builder file.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key arrowImageView.'

If I use UIView as superclass of MyClass, I get error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (MyClass) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewHeaderFooterView instance'

I seen implementation of PSTCollectionView (in PSTRegisterClass function using class_setSuperclass function), but I not understand this solving.

How I can dynamically create UITableViewHeaderFooterView before trying register MyClass?
Or how I can resolve this problem anyway?

Comment: What Duncan C said. You're barking up the wrong tree; don't mess around with runtime stuff. Or, at most, do a runtime check to see if the offending class is available. But it's probably preferable to avoid its use completely and find an alternative. You often find alternative components on Cocoa Controls or CocoaPods that do a similar job to official components, and have better backwards compatability.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to not depend on OS classes that are not supported in the earliest OS version you plan to support. If you absolutely must use the UITableViewHeaderFooterView class, move your deployment target up to 6.0. Otherwise, refactor your code to use a base class that does exist in iOS 5.x, and build your subclass on that.

Trying to use the Objective C runtime to patch in support for missing base classes is a waste of time in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with Your opinion about a waste of time, but I want a deeper understanding Objective-C runtime, if possible.